# Error with scroll element into view with robot framework

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework

[image: Error Details with scroll element into view]

Scrolling to element in robot framework is giving this error. Chrome version: 90.0.4430.72.
Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'm seeing this error too. My guess is that chromedriver 90 has a bug.

Comment: @BryanOakley Interestingly I am not seeing this issue on windows with chrome version 90.0.4430.72 but the issue is happening when I run with in a docker image.

Comment: It could just be a bug on one platform. I and my co-workers use OSX, and several have reported this bug.

Comment: @BryanOakley this worked on another page with in the same test